# Hibernate insert and call store procedure to read non persistent data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a method with transaction annotation that persist an entity and then do a call to an oracle function who read this non persistent data but the function never see the data inserted in the first step. I'm doing this because is function fail then a rollback must be done. Another thing is that the function update a different database.

Any help about how to do this?

Comment: done a flush? defined your transaction isolation level? care to share some actual information ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with this options but it's doesn't work. The main problem than I have is that I can't visualize this implementation, en oracle SP reading non persistent data.

Comment: no idea what you mean by "cant visualize". You have the log stating the SQL executed, and the connection